# Why can't I edit or create my sim?

Tags: the-sims-4

I have sims 4 downloaded through Origin. I have a Mac. It just ran an update and now I can't create a new sim or edit my existing because the character doesn’t show up. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I've read about this a while back and if I'm not mistaken, it's related to iCloud syncing some folders.

> If you have iCloud Drive enabled your Desktop and Documents folders have probably been moved to the cloud during the setup process. This means that every time you load your game it creates a new Sims 4 user data folder as it cannot find the original due to it not being where the game is looking. Please go [here](https://bluebellflora.com/2017/02/06/sims-3-and-sims-4-not-loading-save-games/) for full instructions on how to change your iCloud settings and prevent this from happening. Links explaining iCloud Drive and how it works are also provided in the article.

You can read more from [this link](https://answers.ea.com/t5/The-Sims-Mac/READ-FIRST-Sims-4-Mac-Help-Guides-and-Troubleshooting/m-p/5866220/highlight/true#M6906)